# GitLab pipeline stuck on echo

Tags: gitlab-ci

We've just started to setup GitLab pipelines from this simple .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
stages:
    - building
    - deployment
build:
    stage: building
    script:
        - echo "Build FINISHED!"
deploy to test1:
    stage: deployment
    dependencies:
        - build
    script:
        - echo "Deploy to test1 FINISHED!"
    when: manual
    environment:
        name: test1
        url: http://test1.com/
deploy to test2:
    stage: deployment
    dependencies:
        - build
    script:
        - echo "Deploy to test2 FINISHED!"
    when: manual
    environment:
        name: test2
        url: http://test2.com/
```

But when the pipeline starts, it holds in 'pending' state with 'stuck' label. How can this happend with just echo command?

Comment: Does the first job start at all? I would assume that there is no runner available for performing the task. Have you set up gitlab-runner?

Comment: Thanks Simon! As is turned out, our admin shut down the runner, once it's up the pipeline works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't about `echo` command. Every pipeline job needs a "runner" to work. you can read more about gitlab runners in [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/) page.
You can see your available runners on `Settings > CI/CD > Runnners` section of your repository.
If you have some runners and still pipeline jobs are in pending state, check for runner tags. Each runner have some tags that defines which jobs should use this runner.